# How return more than one match on a list of text?

Tags: python, search, nlp

I currently have a function that yields a term and the sentence it occurs in. At this point, the function is only retrieving the first match from the list of terms. I would like to be able to retrieve all matches instead of just the first.

For example, the `list_of_matches = ["heart attack", "cardiovascular", "hypoxia"]`
and a sentence would be `text_list = ["A heart attack is a result of cardiovascular...", "Chronic intermittent hypoxia is the..."]`

The ideal output is:

```
['heart attack', 'a heart attack is a result of cardiovascular...'],
['cardiovascular', 'a heart attack is a result of cardiovascular...'],
['hypoxia', 'chronic intermittent hypoxia is the...']
```

```
# this is the current function
def find_word(list_of_matches, line):
    for words in list_of_matches:
        if any([words in line]):
            return words, line

# returns list of 'term, matched string'
key_vals = [list(find_word(list_of_matches, line.lower())) for line in text_list if 
find_word(list_of_matches, line.lower()) != None]

# output is currently 
['heart attack', 'a heart attack is a result of cardiovascular...'],
['hypoxia', 'chronic intermittent hypoxia is the...']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution needs 2 steps:

1. fix the function
2. process the output

Given that your disired output follows the pattern

```
    output = [
      [word1, sentence1],
      [word2, sentence1],
      [word3, sentence2],
    ]
```

1. **Fix the function:**
   you should change de return on 'for' loop to iterate over each word of list_of_matches, to get all words that matches and not only the first

. It should stay like this:

```
    def find_word(list_of_matches, line):
        answer = []
        for words in list_of_matches:
            if any([words in line]):
                answer.append([words, line])
        return answer
```

With the function above, the output will be:

```
    key_vals = [
      [
        ['heart attack', 'a heart attack is a result of cardiovascular...'],
        ['cardiovascular', 'a heart attack is a result of cardiovascular...']
      ],
      [
        ['hypoxia', 'chronic intermittent hypoxia is the...']
      ]
    ]
```

2. **Process the output:** Now you need to get the var "key_vals" and process all the list of lists for each sentence processed with the following code:

```
    output = []
    for word_sentence_list in key_vals:
        for word_sentence in word_sentence_list:
            output.append(word_sentence)
```

and, finally, the output will be:

```
    output = [
     ['heart attack', 'a heart attack is a result of cardiovascular...'],
     ['cardiovascular', 'a heart attack is a result of cardiovascular...'],
     ['hypoxia', 'chronic intermittent hypoxia is the...']
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The output from step one works well! But when I try to implement step 2, the second occurrence, in this case 'cardiovascular' disappears.

Comment: This output I posted was with copy/paste from the function. if you're not getting the same answer, you probably made some confusion about the output variables. the output from step one should be the key_vals in the step 2 in order to works properly

Comment: I edited the answer so the output variable names will match properly

Comment: Got it, thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use regex here.

```
import re

def find_all_matches(words_to_search, text):
    matches = []
    for word in words_to_search:
        matched_text = re.search(word, text).group()
        matches.append(matched_text)
    return [matches, text]
```

Please note that this will return a nested list for all the matches.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your response! How would the function be called though? I tried to substitute it for what I already have

 list(find_all_matches(list_of_matches, line.lower())) for line in text_list if find_all_matches(list_of_matches, line.lower()) != None]

and received the following error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

Comment: so lets say you have the keywords you'd want to search: 
words_to_search = ["heart attack", "cardiovascular", "hypoxia"]

and the text is:
text = 'a heart attack is a result of cardiovascular...'

then call:
result = find_all_matches(words_to_search, text)

Comment: if the text is a list, is there a way to iterate through it?

Comment: Could you post some more examples of input and desired output so we can see what you mean?